# Testing GraphQL Apollo and Vue.js

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, mocking, graphql, vue-apollo

I am trying to unit test a component in a Vue.js and Apollo app. The component's general behavior is to query the server, load the response into the `data` of the Vue component. When a button is pushed run a GraphQL mutation and then update the data with the response data. Here's a stub of the component.

```
Vue.extend({
  $apollo: {
    person: {
      query: gql`query($id: ID!) {
        person(id: $id) {
          name
          id
        }
      }`,
      fetch-policy: 'network-only',
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      person: {},
      newPersonId: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getNewPerson() {
      this.$apollo.mutate({
        mutation: gql`mutation($person: Person!) {
          savePerson(person: $Person) {
            person {
              id
            }
          }
        }`,
        update: (store, { data }) {
          ////////////////////////////
          // test-what-happens-here //
          ////////////////////////////        
        }
      })
    }
  }
});
```

My gut says the appropriate tests to write are

```
it('renders the name in correctly on load')
it('sends the correct data with the mutation')
it('does the right thing when the server responds') <--- Most Important
it('does the right thing when the server responds with an error')  <--- Most Important
```

I've written a handful of tests but none seem to be a good pattern for testing the components round trip.

If this were an axios request I would do mock the response to send a 200 and the correct data, and assert axios request was called with the right JSON and the component looked correct, based on a stubbed response.

I cannot for the life of me figure this out with vue-apollo.

They have a decent testing section but the "simple tests" that use apollo cannot test the outcome of a request, and the `graphql-tools` tests don't actually leverage apollo so it misses a pretty significant amount of behavior.

How would you test the update function here in the above code?